# Как из 3 блоков собрать квадратный светофор?

Tags: задание-на-собеседовании

Как решить задачу? Прохожу собеседование на JS разработчика. Решил все задачи кроме одной. Не понимаю, что хотят

> К тебе пришел заказчик со следующим ТЗ:
> На перекресток нужно установить квадратный светофор для проезда машин и он > должен состоять из 3 блоков:
> • Желтый
> • Желтый
> • Красный
> Напиши, что будешь делать.

Comment: Покрашу первый блок в зелёный %)

Comment: 1) ТЗ уточнять вы будете. До того, как код писать, надо убедиться, что Заказчик хотя бы изначально понимает, что ему нужно. 2) И напишете код с возможностью легко заменить цвет, если при приёмке выяснится, что надо иметь зелёный всё же.

Comment: Коллеги, так как лучше ответить на вопрос ?

Comment: Лучше спросить что им нужно и вы не поняли задание.

Answer (score 7):

Это типичный вопрос на проверку softskill, которые сейчас стают очень популярны. Раньше такие вопросы считалось нормально задавать менеджеру, теперь - норма для обычного senior'а.

Правильного ответа - нет. Важен ход рассуждений. Он может быть где то такой - "спрошу, где такое видел или кто подсказал, может это новое изменения в правилах" или может у заказчика просто был вчера слишком хороший день, а сегодня он просто ещё не тонусе. А может это он делает для ребенка и этот перекресток находится внутри игровой комнаты. А может быть заказчик дальтоник, а текст ТЗ переводили с языка, где цвета по другому называются и это была ошибка перевода (мое любимое, когда call function переводят как "кричать функцию")

У меня на одном с собеседований (правда это по с++) показали код, который содержал кучу странного и неопределенного поведения и спросили, что он выведет. По факту, вывод кода сильно зависел от компилятора, опций и фазы Луны. Я ответил где то так - "этот код содержит грубые ошибки (уточнив, что именно), поэтому, обсуждать его вывод - нет смысла. Если у Вас в проекте такой код норма, то мне здесь нечего делать". Меня ещё пару раз пытались спросить, "но все же, что оно выведет?", но потом успокоились. И как я потом с общением с HR понял - это проверка была, не вспылю ли я, можно ли доверить работу с клиентами.

Почему так? Сейчас модно делать все по "скраму-аджайлу", который каждый коверкает как может, но основная мысль - *говорить с заказчиком*, попытаться понять его хотелки (ведь он платит за это!). Иногда сложная непонятная штука может решится часовым миттингом и предложением включить одну галочку/флажок в настройках и получается ещё лучше, чем хотел заказчик. Или микроправкой кода.

Если Вы не понимаете, что с Вас хотят, то это нормально. Просто нужно ещё набраться опыта. Обычно таким вопросом проверяют, может ли человек работать как джун (то есть, будет просто пытаться сделать то, что сказали, не анализируя особо), как токсик (да, это модное слово сейчас) - вспылив и начав с пеной у рта доказывать, что так не делают, это не по правилам, а заказчик просто хотел себе на даче такой светофор и готов за это платить много денег (такое бывает) или нормальный сеньйор-лид, который поговорит с заказчиком, выяснит детали и сделает человека счастливым.

Comment: Я бы всё-таки  вместо по "скраму-аджайлу" в данном контексте заменил на "аджайлу" (в "канбане-аджайле" будет аналогично же:-) ) Agile - образ мышления, Scrum - framework.  И это задача на Agile-манифест, по факту - ценность "Сотрудничество с Заказчиком важнее согласования условий договора" (да и остальные три ценности к такой ситуации отношение имеют).

Comment: о, это большой спорный вопрос. По моему опыту, каждая компания вкладывает в это свое видение. поэтому я так и написал - в кавычках и через дефис.

Comment: Вот поэтому и написано "Agile: Практическое руководство" силами PMI и Agile Alliance (по-моему, в 2019) - там около 1000 экспертов работало (я на его основании пишу в этом вопросе). Полагаю, что после этого документа вкладывать своё видение не очень стоит, так как это будет ненужный спор об определениях:-)

Comment: вот любят люди маленький манифест раздуть до толстых книг. Гнать таких экспертов мокрыми тряпками.

Comment: Зря вы так. Хороший документ. Он для менеджеров (чтобы разработчикам работать не мешали своими нестандартными идеями :-), разработчикам достаточно и манифеста с принципами. И я серьёзно, основная мысль там (хоть и не написана прямо) - "менеджеры, дайте людям работать и просто помогайте, а с самой работой они и без вас справятся":-)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что бы программисты могли работать, пока "менеджеры" читают талмуды и не мешают?:) Ну ну.

Comment: Ну, проектные менеджеры должны еще оборудование вовремя покупать, совещания проводить и протоколировать. Обратите внимание, что в США средняя зарплата ПМа в IT в два раза меньше, чем у девелопера. Ровно потому, что это поддерживающая функция (а в телеком не так, например, с зарплатами - там сложность управления сильно выше).

Comment: это все хорошо, но это совершенно другая история.

Answer (score -1):

Постановка блоков в форме П на боку. горизонтальный желтый, вертикальный желтый и горизонтальный красный. Будет что-то в стиле трамвайного.